# Reading JSON bytes literal in string format

Tags: python, json, unicode, encode

I am reading a previously generated jsonl file. However, I somehow saved the encoded bytes literal, which appears as  `'b'{"foo": "Don\\u2019t", "bar": "bar"}'` and its type is `str`, instead of `b'{"foo": "Don\\u2019t", "bar": "bar"}'`, which is a bytes literal. How could I load it as a dictionary `{"foo": "Don't", "bar": "bar"}`?

Edit: I am doing exactly the same as @snakecharmerb but json.loads seems to fail when loading `{"created_at": "Fri Jan 24 03:22:44 +0000 2020", "id": 1220547456024416256, "id_str": "1220547456024416256", "full_text": "@Aviation_Intel Don\\u2019t forget the Wuhan virus \\ud83e\\udda0", "truncated": false, "display_text_range": [16, 46], "entities": {"hashtags": [], "symbols": [], "user_mentions": [{"screen_name": "Aviation_Intel", "name": "Tyler Rogoway", "id": 613212190, "id_str": "613212190", "indices": [0, 15]}], "urls": []}, "source": "<a href=\\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\\" rel=\\"nofollow\\">Twitter for iPhone</a>", "in_reply_to_status_id": 1220388498873573376, "in_reply_to_status_id_str": "1220388498873573376", "in_reply_to_user_id": 613212190, "in_reply_to_user_id_str": "613212190", "in_reply_to_screen_name": "Aviation_Intel", "user": {"id": 2415399587, "id_str": "2415399587", "name": "Te Sheng Lin \\ud83c\\uddfa\\ud83c\\uddf8", "screen_name": "teshen8lin", "location": "United States", "description": "Opinions Are My Own. You should not treat any opinion expressed by me as a specific inducement to make a particular investment or follow a particular strategy.", "url": null, "entities": {"description": {"urls": []}}, "protected": false, "followers_count": 209, "friends_count": 688, "listed_count": 5, "created_at": "Sun Mar 16 14:58:14 +0000 2014", "favourites_count": 5191, "utc_offset": null, "time_zone": null, "geo_enabled": true, "verified": false, "statuses_count": 14372, "lang": null, "contributors_enabled": false, "is_translator": false, "is_translation_enabled": false, "profile_background_color": "C0DEED", "profile_background_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", "profile_background_tile": false, "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1364327906210627585/6k3p7DI5_normal.jpg", "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1364327906210627585/6k3p7DI5_normal.jpg", "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/2415399587/1614119635", "profile_image_extensions_alt_text": null, "profile_banner_extensions_alt_text": null, "profile_link_color": "1DA1F2", "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED", "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6", "profile_text_color": "333333", "profile_use_background_image": true, "has_extended_profile": false, "default_profile": true, "default_profile_image": false, "following": false, "follow_request_sent": false, "notifications": false, "translator_type": "none"}, "geo": null, "coordinates": null, "place": {"id": "fa9e955670752b3c", "url": "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/fa9e955670752b3c.json", "place_type": "city", "name": "Tenafly", "full_name": "Tenafly, NJ", "country_code": "US", "country": "United States", "contained_within": [], "bounding_box": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-73.9845718, 40.899734], [-73.927398, 40.899734], [-73.927398, 40.937822], [-73.9845718, 40.937822]]]}, "attributes": {}}, "contributors": null, "is_quote_status": false, "retweet_count": 0, "favorite_count": 0, "favorited": false, "retweeted": false, "lang": "en"}` and it shows `JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 462 (char 461)`

Answer (score 2):

For a one-off case, the data can be fixed by removing the leading `b'` and trailing `'` and changing the doubled backslashes to single backslashes in

```
"<a href=\\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\\" rel=\\"nofollow\\">
```

Programatically it can be done by using [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert the stringified bytes to a bytes instance:

```py
import ast, json

# bad_data => single json line
bs = ast.literal_eval(bad_data)
json_data = bs.decode('utf-8') 
data = json.loads(json_data)
```

Note that the encoding of the bytes is assumed; it could be something other than UTF-8.

Both of these methods are *workarounds*.  The *solution* is to fix the upstream program that generates this malformed data.

Note that you can call Python with the `-b` or `-bb` flags to emit warnings or raise exceptions when `str` is called on a bytes instance.

```sh
$ python -b -c 'str(b"")'
<string>:1: BytesWarning: str() on a bytes instance
$ python -bb -c 'str(b"")'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
BytesWarning: str() on a bytes instance
```

Comment: This is super helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As stated in another answer you can directly load bytes data with `json.loads()`, [as in the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage).

If I understand right, you should **decode** bytes data to string and then **load** it with `json.loads()`. Then you will have a dictionary. So something like this:

```
import json

json_string = b'{"foo": "Don\\u2019t", "bar": "bar"}'.decode("utf-8")
dictionary = json.loads(json_string)
```

Answer (score -1):

unless I am missing something or there is something you didnt put in the question you can just give the bytes to json.loads to build the dict

```py
import json

jstring = b'{"foo": "Don\\u2019t", "bar": "bar"}'
print(json.loads(jstring))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'foo': 'Don’t', 'bar': 'bar'}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but it seems that I did not elaborate my question clearly. Please kindly see my edited question. Thanks!

Comment: I have read your edited question but it still doent make any more sense. You have a bytes object, and you want it as a dict. Thats exactly what json.loads is doing